# How to get a pointer back from a void function after it iterates through a string pointer

Tags: c, function, parsing, pointers, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to write a code that goes through a given string using a pointer to parse it.

The original code I wrote worked fine but it was... redundant so I tried making it into a function call to make it more concise. Here is what i have:

```
char inputArray[300];
char buffer[300];
char username[100];
char password[100];
char name[100];
int i=0;

void repeat(char *to)
{
   while(*to!='=')
   {
   to++;
   }
}

void array(char *mm,char *tt)
{
   i=0;
   while(*tt!='+')
   {
   mm[i]=*tt;
   tt++;
   i++;
   }
}

int main()
{
 printf("give me the shit in this fashion: username=?+password=?+real=?\n");
 scanf("%s",inputArray);
 strcpy(buffer,inputArray);
 char *tok=buffer;

 repeat(tok);
 tok++;

 array(username,tok);
 repeat(tok);

 tok++;

 array(password,tok);

 tok++;

 repeat(tok);
 tok++;

 array(name,tok);
 }
```

For some reason it won't give me back the pointer array tok where it left off from the previous function call. why is that? it acts as if after calling it the pointer starts back from the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change your `repeat` to this:

```
void repeat(char **to) {
    while (**to != '=') {
        (*to)++;
    }
}
```

and call it like this:

```
repeat(&tok);
```

and always check for errors:

```
if (scanf("%299s", inputArray) != 1){
    printf("incorrect input\n");
    return 1;
}
```

and your sample code (and add check for errors in `array` and `repeat` to not go out of bounds):

```
#include <inttypes.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

char inputArray[300];
char buffer[300];
char username[300];
char password[300];
char name[300];
int i = 0;

void repeat(char **to) {
    while (**to != '=') {
        (*to)++;
    }
}
void array(char *mm, char *tt){
    i = 0;
    while (*tt != '+')  {
        mm[i] = *tt;
        tt++;
        i++;
    }
}
int main() {
    printf("give me the shit in this fashion: username=?+password=?+real=?\n");
    if (scanf("%299s", inputArray) != 1){
        printf("incorrect input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    inputArray[299] = 0;
    strcpy(buffer, inputArray);
    char *tok = buffer;

    repeat(&tok);
    tok++;

    array(username, tok);
    repeat(&tok);

    tok++;

    array(password, tok);

    tok++;

    repeat(&tok);
    tok++;

    array(name, tok);
}
```

and you may use this to not go out of bounds:

```
#include <inttypes.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>


char* read_str(char *src, char *dst){
    char *p, *q;
    p = src;
    while (*p != 0 && *p != '=') p++;
    if (*p == 0) {
        *dst = 0;
        return NULL; // '=' not found
    }
    p++;

    q = p;
    while (*q != 0 && *q != '+') q++;
    //if (*q == 0)  return NULL;// '+' not found

    while (p <= q) *dst++ = *p++;
    dst--;
    *dst = 0;
    q++;
    return q;
}
#define MAX_LEN 100
int main() {
    char username[MAX_LEN];
    char password[MAX_LEN];
    char name[MAX_LEN];
    char  inputArray[MAX_LEN] = "username=Alex+password=123+real=Alex";
    char *p = inputArray;

    p = read_str(p, username);
    if (p == NULL)return 1; // error
    p = read_str(p, password);
    if (p == NULL)return 1; // error
    read_str(p, name);

    printf("username: %s \n", username);
    printf("password: %s \n", password);
    printf("    name: %s \n", name);
}
```

Comment: is it normal that I get a segmentation fault after it goes through the first character?

Comment: @harekuin: no, try sample code. and input correct string and add check for errors in array and repeat to not go out of bounds

Comment: thank you so much for the really descriptive code! :D

Answer (score 1):

Functions receive *copies* of their arguments. Original arguments remain unaffected.

Giving something back has a special syntax in C: the `return` statement. Thus

```
char* repeat (char *to) // <- this function gives back a char*
{
   while (*to != '=')
   {
     to++;
   }
   return to; // <- giving something back
}
```

Call it like this:

```
tok = repeat(tok);
```

Treat `array` in the same fashion.

Note 1, this function will result in *undefined behaviour if the string doesn't contain `'='`.

Note 2, it is also possible to pass a pointer to `tok` as the other answer suggests, but for sake of clarity it is only recommended to use this style when you need to return more than one thing from a function.